# Verilog FSM controller and datapath

Tags: verilog, hdl, fsm

The code below shows a finite state machine that controls a separate datapath module to find the GCD of two 4-bit numbers. I am currently getting the following errors, and I'm not sure why. Maybe they are due to some syntax I'm not aware of:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Xilinx Stuff/GCD123/Controller.v" Line 48: Syntax error near ";".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Xilinx Stuff/GCD123/Controller.v" Line 59: Syntax error near ";".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Xilinx Stuff/GCD123/Controller.v" Line 62: Syntax error near ";".
```

The code where the errors are encountered is below:

```
module Controller(start,reset,x_sel,y_sel,xlty,xgty,xequaly,clk);

    input   start,clk, reset, xlty, xgty,xequaly;
    output x_sel,y_sel;

    
    // Declare state register
    reg     [1:0]state;
    
    // Declare states
    parameter S0 = 0, S1 = 1, S2 = 2, S3 = 3, S4 = 4;
    
    
    debounce startd(.clock(clk),.noisy(start),.clean(clean_start));
    
    always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset)
            state <= S0;
        else
            case (state)
                S0:
                    if (clean_start)
                        state <= S1;
                    else
                        state <= S0;
                S1:
                    x_sel <= 0;
                    y_sel <= 0;
                    state <= S2;
                S2:
                    if (xlty)
                        state <= S3;
                    else if(xgty)
                        state <= S4;
                    else if(xequaly)
                        state <= S5;
                S3:
                    y_sel <= 1;
                    state <= S2;
                S4:
                    x_sel <= 1;
                    state <= S2;
                S5:
                    state <= S0;

            endcase
    end
    
endmodule
```

The lines that have the errors are `y_sel <= 0;` in the `S1` state, `state <= S2;` in the `S4` state and `state <= S2;` in the `S3` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `begin/end` keywords around consecutive statements:

```
module Controller(start,reset,x_sel,y_sel,xlty,xgty,xequaly,clk);
input   start,clk, reset, xlty, xgty,xequaly;
output x_sel,y_sel;


// Declare state register
reg     [1:0]state;

// Declare states
parameter S0 = 0, S1 = 1, S2 = 2, S3 = 3, S4 = 4;


debounce startd(.clock(clk),.noisy(start),.clean(clean_start));

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset)
        state <= S0;
    else
        case (state)
            S0:
                if (clean_start)
                    state <= S1;
                else
                    state <= S0;
            S1:
              begin
                x_sel <= 0;
                y_sel <= 0;
                state <= S2;
              end
            S2:
                if (xlty)
                    state <= S3;
                else if(xgty)
                    state <= S4;
                else if(xequaly)
                    state <= S5;
            S3:
              begin
                y_sel <= 1;
                state <= S2;
              end
            S4:
              begin
                x_sel <= 1;
                state <= S2;
              end
            S5:
                state <= S0;

        endcase
end

endmodule
```

Comment: In addition to `begin / end` the output ports `x_sel` and `y_sel` should be declared as `reg` parameters. Also `S5` should be in the `parameter` list.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. @Amir the x_sel and y_sel basically serve as select lines to 2 separate multiplexers that are implemented in a separate datapath module. The controller here simply sets them high or low depending on what it wants the datapath to do. Would declaring them as reg parameters allow them to serve this function?

Comment: All parameters that are assigned in the `always` block, should be declared as `reg` parameter. If always is sensitive to `clk`, this parameters are synchronous with `clk`. It means the select lines of the multiplexers are synchronous with `clk` and is changed on `clk` rising or falling edge.